# What is the limits of OpenShift database usage?

Tags: openshift

I recently start trying OpenShot, coming from Heroku where they give a very limited free database storage, I'm wondering what is the limit of OpenShot's database storage, does it just has to fit within the gear's quota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database can be as big as your free gear space will allow.  You have 1GB to use, but remember that their are other files on there taking up space also.  And if you have the database gear co-located with your web gear, that will eat into your space as well.